# How to get fork join/join_any to work with a loop

Tags: system-verilog, fork-join

As per the [SV LRM section 9.3.2](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

```
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
fork
    automatic int k = j;
    begin
        .... # use k here
    end
join_none
```

this is how to create a `fork` in a loop. I have tried it and it works. But if i want to create fork with `join` and not `join_none` in loop it does not work as expected but works sequentially.

How can i modify this to work using a `join`, i want all my forks to fork off simultaneously and then wait for all of them to finish(`join`) or one of them to finish(`join_any`)?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to wait for all of the processes fork'ed by the `fork-jone_none` to complete, you put a `wait fork;` statement after the for loop. The `wait fork` statements waits for all child processes of the current thread to complete.

Id there are processes created by `fork-jone_none` before this `for` loop still active that you do not want to wait for, you need to put this piece of of code in an isolation thread.

```
fork
  some_other_process;
join_none
fork 
  begin : isolation_process
    for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j) begin : for_loop
      fork
         automatic int k = j;
         begin
            .... # use k here
         end
      join_none
    end : for_loop
  wait fork; // will not wait for some other process
 end :isolation_thread
 join
```

To get the behavior of the `fork-join_any` requires some handshaking signal or event in each process to signal that it is done.

```
event join_any_event;
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j) begin : for_loop
      fork
         automatic int k = j;
         begin
            .... # use k here
            ->> join_any_event;
         end
      join_none
    end : for_loop
  @join_any_event;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `wait fork`. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 9.6.1 *Wait fork statement*

> The **wait fork** statement blocks process execution flow until all immediate child subprocesses (processes created by the current process, excluding their descendants) have completed their execution.

Add the `wait fork` after your for-loop to get the desired effect:

```
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
fork
    automatic int k = j;
    begin
        .... # use k here
    end
join_none

wait fork; // wait for all the above fork-join_none to complete
```

Comment: Greg and I answered alike at the same time. But be careful - `wait fork` does not just wait for the _above_ `fork-join_none` it waits for _all_ fork-join_none` child processes of the current process. This is a very common mistake. See my example